# Ethics of "recycling" assignments

Tags: ethics, university, assessment

I can't think of a better title, feel free to edit.

I'm retaking a course at university, and the basic assessments are very similar; if I can assume that I'm studying effectively, could there be any issues with modifying my assignments to fit the new criteria, and effectively resubmitting them?

From my perspective, this cannot be collaboration or collusion, but it could be defined as plagiarism, at least by a computer. I don't see why I would have to reference my own work here if it is adapted from previous writings, is it therefore sensible to assume that there will be no complication from an ethical perspective?

I'm also interested in the general concept for academia - would I have to reference my previous writings, and if so, how?

Edit: Let me clarify that this particular case is not a significant assignment, but rather a small "checkpoint".

Comment: *It makes very little sense to reference my own work* - Why does it make very little sense? It makes perfect sense to me to reference your own work.

Comment: My apologies, I'm not familiar with extended writings as such, most of my assignments are on a case by case basis. I had thought that it could be considered my notes as such, and not needed to be referenced. I had thought for example, that I would not need to write "adapted from 'Ethics in Academia', Oman, 2015" on a future comment here

Comment: If you are retaking the class, why would you want to recycle the assignments from last time? (unless the reason you're retaking is strictly nonacademic).

Comment: Without going into detail, these smaller assignments are rather trivial and (in my opinion) take a lot more time than they are worth, I'd rather be working problems than writing an investigation on a day one concept. I can understand your point, and I'm somewhat interested in the general concepts, I don't intend to resubmit my more important assignments such as a full report.

Comment: Hasn't this question been asked before?

Comment: @NateEldredge I didn't see that one there, it's a hard question to phrase, thanks. It didn't quite answer all of my questions, but it covered most of it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ask your professor. Opinions about this may vary substantially from instructor to instructor. In additional a lot of can depend on the nature of the assignments (are you writing a paper on a topic of your choice, or proving a theorem that has been assigned to you, for example?).

When writing scholarly papers, you should always cite your own work if it is relevant enough that you would have cited it had it had a different author. Furthermore, if you re-use any figures or substantial amount of text from a previous paper, you need to be careful to indicate this very clearly lest someone complain that you are committing self-plagiarism. (No judgement implied here; my own views on the issue of self-plagiarism are complicated and probably go beyond the scope of the question.)

Comment: These assignments are somewhat trivial, but time consuming when considered as a whole. They could be considered as checkpoints, as I added above.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by "checkpoints", but in any case you need to check with your instructor.

Comment: Sorry, it's hard to describe them otherwise, they are simple assignments that cover basic concepts explained in lectures. Thank you for the additional information as well, what if you had modified or extended a paper that had been rejected by a panel, would the same apply?

Comment: @Oman If a paper has not been published previously, e.g. because it has been rejected, it is not self-plagiarism to publish it after further revision (or even without). In addition, one can freely post a paper on a preprint server such as the arXiv and then publish it formally in a journal or a conference proceedings. Only a few dinosaurs of publishers continue to object to such.